# adding dynamic url in odata web api

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I like to know how to configure the odata routing so that I can have 
URL/odata/{databaseName}/SalesOrder

example
URL/odata/mydatabase1/SalesOrder
URL/odata/mydatabase2/SalesOrder

And then the controller to be able to retrieve the databaseName token.

I have tried to add

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "databaseName", model: GetModel());
```

but that does not quite work.

Answer (score 0):

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "{companyId}/odata", model: GetModel());
```

Above code needed to go in to WebApiConfig and then within your controller

```
var company = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["companyId"];
```